# Clicking instead of dragging to expand the notification bar

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is there anyway to configure the notification bar so that it gets expanded when I click on it (i.e. no need to drag it)?

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.